# Why the value of user.name property in application.yml is wrong?

Tags: java, spring, yaml

That is a simple problem.
I hava a `application.yml`:

```
server:
  port: 852

user:
  name: Jack
  name1: Tom
  description: ${user.name}
```

And a User Java class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String name1;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getName1() {
        return name1;
    }
    public void setName1(String name1) {
        this.name1 = name1;
    }   
}
```

And finally there is a MVC Controller java class:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @Autowired User user;   

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String getUser() {
        return user.getName() + "--------" + user.getDescription() + "----" + user.getName1();
    }   
}
```

Ok,there is seem correct, but when entered "localhost:852/user" at browser address,I got wrong result as follow:

```
BG221726--------BG221726----Tom
```

Note that,"BG221726" is my computer name! What's wrong with my code????

Comment: `user.name` is a java system property containing the username of the logged in system user, which takes precedence over your property file.

Comment: Okey,thanks,How can I find the java system property in your say. :)

Answer (score 5):

You are using, effectively, `user.name` which is a [special system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) set by java. And when using the [property resolving mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) system properties take precedence over the ones loaded from property files, that one is taken.

To overcome use a different prefix.

Comment: Thank  you very much  :)

Comment: I had a variable named 'username' in a spring Configuration class. It mapped to a different property (say, x.y.z). But it would be assigned value of system user. Renaming variable helped.